# Unable to load pre-trained gensim Doc2Vec from publication data

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, doc2vec, pre-trained-model

I want to use an already trained Doc2Vec from a published paper.

**Paper**

> Whalen, R., Lungeanu, A., DeChurch, L., & Contractor, N.
> (2020). Patent Similarity Data and Innovation Metrics. Journal of
> Empirical Legal Studies, 17(3), 615–639.
> https://doi.org/10.1111/jels.12261

**Code**

> https://github.com/ryanwhalen/patent_similarity_data

**Data**

> https://zenodo.org/record/3552078#.YeWkFvgxmUk

However, when trying to load the model (patent_doc2v_10e.model) an error is raised. **Edit**: The file can be downloaded from the data repository (link above). I am not the author of the paper nor the creator of the model.

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
model = Doc2Vec.load("patent_doc2v_10e.model")


FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'patent_doc2v_10e.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy'
```

Am I missing files or do I have to load the model in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did the file `patent_doc2v_10e.model` come from?

If trying to load that file, it generates such an  error about another file with the name `patent_doc2v_10e.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy`, then that other file is a necessary part of the full model that should have been created alongside `patent_doc2v_10e.model` when that `patent_doc2v_10e.model` file was first `.save()`-persisted to disk.

You'll need to go back to where `patent_doc2v_10e.model` was created, & find the extra missing  `patent_doc2v_10e.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy` file (& possibly others also starting `patent_doc2v_10e.model…`). All such files created at the same `.save()` must be kept/moved together, at the same filesystem path, for any future `.load()` to succeed.

(Additionally, if you are training these yourself from original data, I'd suggest being sure to use a current version of Gensim. Only older pre-4.0 versions will create any save files with `trainables` in the name.)

Comment: I provided further information in the original post through an edit.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue remains: if trying to load file `'patent_doc2v_10e.model'` triggers an error requesting another file `'patent_doc2v_10e.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy'`, then that other file should have been provided alongside the main  `'patent_doc2v_10e.model'` file. Otherwise, it's incomplete & shouldn't be offered as a usable file. You may need to contact the authors/uploaders of the 'US Patent Similarity Data' files to tell them they've provided incomplete-to-the-point-of-brokenness files.